# Regular Expressions for 16 digits and forward slash?

Tags: javascript, regex

ok so I am currently trying to use a regular expression to validate that my string has 16 numbers. Also a MM/YYYY format. They aren't working.

```
var cc = ccnum.value;
cc = cc.replace(/\s/g, '');
cc = cc.replace(/-/g, '');
//Validate the credit card number:
if (/^\d{16}$/.test(cc.value)) {
    removeErrorMessage('ccnum');
} else {
    addErrorMessage('ccnum', 'Please enter a valid credit card number.');
    error = true;
}
```

and

```
if (/^\d{2}?\d{4}$/.test(exp.value) && (expDate[0] >= month) && (expDate[1] >= year)) {
```

Comment: "16 numbers" _and_ "MM/YYYY format" ? totaling 24 characters , or 15 numbers , including a single `/` , totaling 16 characters ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Regex to validate the string which contains exactly 16 digits or not.

```
^\d{16}$
```

Regex to validate this `MM/YYYY` format

```
^\d{2}\/\d{4}$
```

Example:

```
> /^\d{16}$/.test('1234567890987654')
true
> /^\d{16}$/.test('12345678909876545')
false
> /^\d{16}$/.test('712345678909876545')
false
> /^\d{16}$/.test('123456789098765')
false
```

Comment: Ok the mm/yyyy format worked but the 16 digit one didnt. I started with that code too. I made sure my input is 16 digits long too.

Comment: @AvinVarghese op's trying to validate the format only.. ie two digits , a slash , 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to validate this `MM/YYYY` format

```
^0[1-9]|1[0-2]\/\d{4}$
```